# phpspreadsheet password protected

Tags: excel, passwords, phpspreadsheet

With **phpspreadsheet**

Is there a way to protect the Excel sheet with a password so users cannot read without the password?

I know you can protect a cell or a sheet from writing but I am looking for a way to protect the entire file from being open, once the user open it, it will pop up the "enter password" screen

Comment: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet

If you happen to figure out how to unlock a workbook with PHPSpreadsheet, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting security on a spreadsheet

Excel offers 3 levels of "protection":

1. Document: allows you to set a password on a complete spreadsheet, allowing changes to be made only when that password is entered.
2. Worksheet: offers other security options: you can disallow inserting rows on a specific sheet, disallow sorting, ...
3. Cell: offers the option to lock/unlock a cell as well as show/hide the internal formula.
   An example on setting document security:

   `$spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
   $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
   $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("PhpSpreadsheet");`

An example on setting worksheet security:

```
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword('PhpSpreadsheet');
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
   $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
```

An example on setting cell security:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->
getStyle('B1')->
getProtection()->
setLocked(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```

Make sure you enable worksheet protection if you need any of the worksheet protection features! This can be done using the following code:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
```

Comment: This only prevents editing of the document/worksheet/cell. It does not prevent viewing of the data, as per the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because phpspreadsheet does not implement this function, but you can export the file first and then use https://github.com/nick322/secure-spreadsheet package to protect sensitive XLSX files.

```php
use Nick\SecureSpreadsheet\Encrypt;

$test = new Encrypt();
$test->input('Book1.xlsx')
    ->password('111')
    ->output('bb.xlsx');
```

Answer (score -3):

On Excel 2016 ( mileage may vary between versions )

Open your spreadsheet and go to:

- File >
- Info >
- Protect Workbook > Encrypt With Password

And put in a password, this will prompt the user when opening.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I edited my question as I need it with **phpspreadsheet** not in excel iteself